# SQL Server Timeouts First Time Application Loads

Tags: sql-server, database, timeout, vpn

I've recently switched to running my development environment over our company's VPN using NetExtender.  It would now seem that my database driven applications are now timing out the first time they try to hit the database.  After the timeout (30 sec or so) and an additional 5-10 seconds, all DB calls succeed.  During the 5-10 seconds the timeout error response is sent immediately.  It seems to be related to when SQL Server needs to create a new database session for me.  Each time I need to be assigned a new client process ID, I timeout.  This is a huge problem when using Resharper + NUnit as a test harness as each time the tests are run, a new instance of resharper's unit test runner is created thusly causing me to timeout.  Server timeout seems to be in the area of 30 seconds, which is certainly generous enough for a connection to be established.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like it could be a DNS issue. If the primary DNS is not properly configured and is inaccessible from the VPN client, it will timeout and pass on to the secondary.

Additionally, some VPNs allow you to access some local resources - this could put the DNS on your own, local network in play.

I think I'd try changing the DNS-order and see if that did the trick.